# WPF Combobox - Setting text through binding whilst control has focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Ok, I give up and need some help.

I'm struggling to get a WPF ComboBox to behave how I want it to!  To briefly describe the problem, I have a ComboBox that limits down its contents as the user types stuff into it.  So, for example, when they type a C into the box the ComboBox's items are limited to things that begin with a C.  All well and good.  The trouble I am having is that when there is only 1 option left in the box I want the only item left to be selected and for the ComboBox's text to be set to that item.  It selects the item well enough but I can't get the ComboBox's text to update as desired.  Here is the XAML for the ComboBox:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="CustomerBox" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCustomer.AccountCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValuePath="AccountCode"
              Text="{Binding CustomerBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              PreviewKeyDown="CustomerBox_PreviewKeyDown">
```

The code for the text property is as follows:

```
    private string _customerBoxText;
    public string CustomerBoxText
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerBoxText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_customerBoxText != value)
            {
                _customerBoxText = value;
                GetCustomerData(value);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("CustomerBoxText");
        }
    }
```

GetCustomerData limits the contents of the box by changing the Customers collection the combobox is bound to.  It's code is this:

```
    private void GetCustomerData(string accountCode = "")
    {
        List<Customer> customers = (Helpers.DataStorage.Instance.GetData<Customer>(accountCode) as List<Customer>).OrderBy(x => x.AccountCode).ToList();
        this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(customers);
        // If only 1 item in list then we make it the selected item
        if (this.Customers.Count == 1)
        {
            SelectedCustomer = Customers[0];
            CustomerBoxText = SelectedCustomer.AccountCode;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedCustomer = Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AccountCode == accountCode);
        }
    }
```

I've not finished working on it yet so this is code in progress.  The trouble I am having is with this section:

```
        if (this.Customers.Count == 1)
        {
            SelectedCustomer = Customers[0];
            CustomerBoxText = SelectedCustomer.AccountCode;
        }
```

The SelectedCustomer is updated fine enough and I can see the values coming through from that in other bindings.  However, CustomerBoxText being updated does not update the value typed in the ComboBox.  I've used snoop to confirm that the Text property is the value expected but it not the value shown in the ComboBox itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I would look into `AutoCompleteBox` from wpftoolkit instead of trying to implement it with `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't seem to find the AutoCompleteBox in the WPF toolkit.  I've not used it before so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Ignore that last comment.  Turns out there are multiple things with names similar to wpftoolkit and I got the wrong one!  I'll have a look and see if it fits my needs

Comment: In the code you posted, I would be concerned that you may wind up recursively setting the `CustomerBoxText` property. While it might not be unbounded recursion, it still seems likely to cause problems if the code isn't designed for re-entrancy. That said, if you still find that you want help with this question, please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. If you cannot or will not provide a good code example, please close and/or delete the question.

Comment: The recursion was a concern I had but something I wasn't going to worry about until I know if it will play nice or not.  If you set the text property whilst it has focus should I expect the change to be seen?  I snooped the control and the text property was as expected (i.e. it was the complete AccountCode) but in the control I only saw the partial text that I had typed.  This seems odd to me, how can the combobox have its text property be one value but display a different value, and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or I'm asking the ComboBox something it is not capable of doing.

Comment: @Tominator when you tried looking at the Text property, have you also checked the Customers property if it contained a single item?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I'm using the AutoCompleteBox as suggested by @ghord now and it behaving as I expect (thanks!).  I'd like to understand why the ComboBox wasn't working as expected but unfortunately I changed a lot of stuff and don't have a back up of the code as it was with the ComboBox so it would be hard to check it now.